# Selecting rows before and after rows based on value of other group--pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'Country':['UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK'],
    'Product':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
            'Week': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 
       'val': [5,4,3,1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    }

have = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Country','Product','Week', 'val'])

print(have)
```

[image]

i want to select rows before and after of last week of product A. i.e.week number 4 and product B rows should be 4 rows and before week was 3 and after weeks are 5,6 and including week 4 so total 4. Here's the wanted output

[image]

Comment: Could you please post sample input and sample expected output in form of text in your question. It is always recommended to post samples in form of text NOT in images because people can test their codes with text samples, kindly do the same and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['Country', 'Product', 'Week', 'val'])

max_week = df.loc[df["Product"].eq("A"),"Week"].max()

print (df[df["Product"].eq("A")|((df["Week"]>=max_week-1)&(df["Week"]<=max_week+2))])

#
  Country Product  Week  val
0      UK       A     1    5
1      UK       A     2    4
2      UK       A     3    3
3      UK       A     4    1
6      UK       B     3    7
7      UK       B     4    8
8      UK       B     5    9
9      UK       B     6   10
```